# Need an OAuth2 server that supports "client credentials" grant type

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

I need to get authenticated using OAuth2 client credentials as the grant type. The app would need to call the OAuth2 server with only the client id and client secret, get authenticated and receive an access token back, then the app can use the access token to obtain the application's data. There is no regular user involved and the data belongs to the app. This is the same concept as your application connects to the database with a user name and user password belong to the application. The user uses the application without any knowledge of backend database accesses.

There are so many OAuth2 servers that support "code" grant type such as Google, Facebook, Github, but I have not found anyone that supports client credentials. Google asks me to set a service account, it is not the same as client credentials. Does anyone know an OAuth2 server that I use to test my client credential grant code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak has support for client credentials as authentication for the token endpoint.

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_authentication_methods

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old question, you can use Gitlab API.

```
 curl --request POST --url "https://gitlab.com/oauth/token" --form "grant_type=client_credentials" --form  "client_id=<your-client-id" --form  "client_secret=<your-client-secret>"
```